# replace newline string literal - '\n' in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string literal, `\n` in a variable. I am trying to replace it with empty string. But it doesn't work.

```
var value = "\\\n"
value = value.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "")
console.log(value)
```

value evaluates to the string literal - `\n`. I expect no output from `console.log`. But it prints

```
\
```

Empty line followed by a backward slash (for some reason, stack overflow has trimmed the empty line in above output).

Note, this question is not related to replacing newline character -`\n`

Comment: Why would you expect no output?

Comment: that is a smaller example of my complex problem

Comment: `"\\\n"` produces a backslash followed by a line break. If your string literally contains `\n`, it would be `"\\n"`. At this point I'm not sure what string value you really have.

Comment: awesomee..... you have an eye for errors.... the error is in the variable, not in the pattern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have string literal, `\n` in a variable

No you don't. You have `\(newline)`, which is a quite different thing.

```
var value = "\\\n"
```

`value` is a string of length two. The first character is a backslash. The second character is a newline.

```
value = value.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "")
```

Your regexp attempts to replace a literal backslash followed by either the letter  `r` or the letter `n`. But your input contains a newline in the second position. A newline matches neither `r` nor `n`. Hence nothing is replaced, and `value` retains its original value.

To see this more clearly:

```
> for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) console.log(value.charCodeAt(i));
< 92
< 10  // this is a newline
```

You may have been confused by some non-intuitive behavior in the Chrome devtools console. `console.log('\n')` prints an empty line as expected. However, `console.log('a\n')` prints only the `a`, with no apparent newline. In other words, Chrome devtools (as well as FF) appears to suppress the final trailing newline in certain situations.

Comment: what is the recommended solution for someone who wants to replace the literal string characters "\n" with an empty string?

Answer (score 6):

Don't do like `\\[rn]`. ie, Don't separate backslash and `r`, `n` . This would change its meaning.

```
value.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "")
```

If you also want to replace the backslash character which exists before carriage return or newline character then add `\\` before the character class.

```
value.replace(/\\[\r\n]+/g, "")
```

Comment: `[\r\n]` -- anything inside a square bracket is a character class.. in a character class, i read somewhere, backslash is like a normal character. does backslash retain its special property inside square brackets too?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar: Most special characters loose their "specialty", but ``\`` is *not* one of them.

Comment: regex won't treat the backslashed chars like `\t`, `\r`, `\n` as seperate chars since \ alone won't have any special meaning.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
value = value.replace(/\\[\r\n]+/g, "");
// ""
```

This will replace `\r` or `\n` which is followed by a literal `\` in your input.

Answer (score 0):

This one works pretty well `.replace(/\\r\\n?|\\n/g, '\n');`